# Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'out' not found

Tags: r

here is my code:i am getting this error Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'out' not found

```
 ana <- function(x) { out<-data.frame()
    nr<-1
       for (f in 1:length(x)) { 
fdata<-data.frame()
      fdata <- as.data.frame(x[[f]][[1]],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      fdata[nr:nr+nrow(fdata)-1,]<-as.data.frame(fdata$txt,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        }
      out[,f] <- fdata;
     nr<-nr+20
    }
    return(out)
```

i have properly called out and fdata but still the problem persists. thanks for helping.

Comment: You're calling `return(out)` after the function call ends with the `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be easy to fix, 
your return is outside of the function
return(out) needs to be placed under "nr->nr+20"

as "out" only visible within the function 
out variable is undefined

br